# Alterando a largura da tela faz desaparecer barra de rolagem horizontal

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, jquery-datatables

Segue o exemplo em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31217/

Segue a imagem do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a imagem como deve ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Navegadores testados:

Google Chrome Versão 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit): Não apresenta o problema

Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393: Problema

Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) - Problema: (Imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opera 43.0 Problema - (Imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução ?

Comment: coloca `.DTFC_RightBodyLiner {
    overflow-y: unset !important;
}` no seu css que o problema do Opera e do Edge resolve

Comment: aqui no meu ... a barra nao desaparece... ela continua aparecendo mas ela nao funciona. o.O

Comment: legal man... voce sabe que pode postar a resposta pra sua pergunta né? assim se alguem tiver o mesmo problema. vai saber como resolver ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema, era a classe `table-responsive` que envolve em um elemento de rolagem que conflita muito mal com o redimensionamento DataTable.

Então só remover linha: `<div class="table-responsive">` que resolve o problema.